# How to convert arrays to a list without using build in methods

Tags: c#

Hi guys i want to ask the best practise of converting arrays in to a list by creating my own method.
I am thinking a foreach loop to take the items from the arrays to the list but i am struggling on the implementation.

please a bit of advice will be really helpful.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Why your own method? Why not use `.ToList()`? Is this a homework exercise?

Comment: Also, where do you draw the line on built-in methods? Are constructors okay? How about `List<T>`s `Add()` and `AddRange()` methods? Those are built-in.

Comment: yea i cannot use any build in methods the other option will be loops i did a static list<T> and a method array were i added 10 elements of numbers.

Comment: "i am struggling"...please show what you tried then, and explain what it does so far, and what, if anything goes wrong. Also please define "best practice" as you see it. That's a potentially subjective term (which makes it difficult for us to answer) and is not necessarily the same as "it works". And as mentioned, what you consider to be "built-in" would be useful to know. Frankly it's hard to see how you could do much to a List without using that class's methods, since the internals are...well...internal, and not accessible. Unless you are supposed to implement your own version of List?

Comment: class Program
    {
        static List<int[]> MyList = new List<int[]> ();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
        }
        static void Arrays()
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[10]; //create an array with 10 int values
            numbers[0] = 3;
            numbers[1] = 25;
            numbers[2] = 61;
            numbers[3] = 70;
            numbers[4] = 85;
            numbers[5] = 90;
            numbers[6] = 102;
            numbers[7] = 131;
            numbers[8] = 164;
            numbers[9] = 180;
       }

Comment: @chris, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62291453/edit) your question with the relevant code rather than trying to post it in the comments.

Comment: As you can hopefully see yourself, that code is unreadable in the comments like that. Your question has an "edit" button just below it. Please use it to add all your extra info to your post, instead of bits and pieces in the comments. That also means you can [format it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since the `List` class is really a wrapper around arrays, and it has a constructor that takes an array parameter that initializes the list, you can just pass the array to the list constructor:

```
public static List<T> GetListFromArray<T>(T[] input)
{
    return input == null ? null : new List<T>(input);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var itemArray = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var itemList = GetListFromArray(itemArray);
```

Comment: yea but that doesn't satisfy the exercise need i need to create my own method using loops so i am guessing my own list maybe?

Comment: @chris the wording in your question doesn't mention that. If you've been set an excercise, can you please update your question with the exact wording of what you've been asked to do. Otherwise we're all just going to be keeping on guessing what you really mean/want.

Comment: Ok, I eidtied the answer and made it a method, but if you can't to call any built-in method like `Add()`, `AddRange`, or `Insert`, then I don't see how you can add items in a loop. Typically the way you'd do it is to use indexing to add items, something like: `someList[0] = someArray[0];`. However, a `List` does not start with any items in it, even if you specify the starting capacity in the constructor, so this won't work - it will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This must be for homework. And you can't figure it out?

```
public List<T> Array2List<T>( T[] array )
{
  List<T> list = new List<T>();
  foreach ( int element in array )
  {
    list.Add(element);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: *"I cannot use any build in methods"* is the requirement that I can't get past. You have to call a method (like `Add` above) to add items to an empty List in a loop.

Comment: if i could use the add method i would have done it i tried also indexing Rufus and it doesn't work.

Comment: If you can't use *any* built-in methods, you're going to have to roll your own implementation of of `List<T>`. Even its indexer, `Item[]` is a method in `List<T>`. See the source code at https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,174 — if you can't use *any& built-in methods, you're going to have to (1) subclass `List<T>` and (2) override *every* method and property to provide your own implementation. That can't possibly be what your instructor is after.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need your own method in my own opinion, or you can do as well.

```
using System.Linq;

    public List<int> ConvertMyArrayToList(int[] myarray){
           return myarray.ToList(); 
    }
```

you can check for null and other validations. 
Or

```
public List<int> ConvertMyArrayToList(int[] myarray)
    {
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in myarray)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
        return result;
    }


       public  List<int> ConvertMyArrayToList(int[] myarray)
        {

            List<int> myList = new List<int>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in myarray)
            {

                myList.Insert(i, item);
                i++;
            }
            return myList;
        }
```

Comment: I think `.ToList()` would probably count as a "built-in" method by the OP's definition.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, but what else does? As you mentioned in another comment, in order to use a `List<T>`, you need to use a built-in method. OP should make clear which methods they want to avoid so we can all stop dancing around it.

Comment: @itsme86 well yes. But also I kind of think from a literal standpoint, Rufus L's answer has nailed it - as long as you consider a constructor to be different from a method :-) It does sound like a bit of a homework-y semi-trick question though.

Comment: A lot of people don't seem to know about the existence of the [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-3.1) method. There's no need to have your own loop.